# Закодированный JSON при поиске по элементам jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Из `PHP` в браузер приходит `select`, в котором атрибут `value` каждого `option` содержит закодированный `JSON`. Одна из функций скрипта ищет внутри него `option` по указанному значению `value`, но сталкиваюсь с ошибкой `jQuery`:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Держать закодированный объект в `value` удобно - при отправке формы он автоматически передается на сервер. Подскажите, как можно решить проблему.

```
<input value="[{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;price&quot;}]"/>

<select>
  <option value="1">-- 1</option>
  <option value="[{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;price&quot;}]">-- 2</option>
</select>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var value = jQuery('input').val();
  var result = jQuery('option[value="' + value + '"]').text();
  
  alert(result);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g5fo8wpa/

Comment: а зачем декодировать json в атрибутах? почему нельзя сделать обычный?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский объект `json` передается с сервера и записывается в атрибут - потом при отправке формы он опять передается на сервер и там раскодируется. То есть, в браузере только хранится, этот объект не создается в браузере.

Comment: я это понял с первого раза. а вы мой вопрос не поняли. почему нельзя вписать в атрибуты "чистый" json, без всяких `htmlentities` или что вы там используете?

Comment: "Держать закодированный объект в value удобно" - этот вопрос показывает что __нет__, не удобно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский объект преобразуется в `JSON` при помощи `htmlspecialchars(json_encode())` - если использовать просто `json_encode()`, то браузер неправильно его воспринимает, рушится разметка.

Comment: может из-а юникода внутри? и нужно флаг давать JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ?   В общем ответ на вопрос "Подскажите, как можно решить проблему" --- корректно сгенерировать строку json  в атрибутах.  попробовать флаги в первую очередь надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все дело в кавычках, просто экранируйте их `replace(/"/g, '\\"')`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = $('input').val().replace(/"/g, '\\"');
  var result = $('option[value="' + value + '"]').text();
  alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="[{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;price&quot;}]" />

<select>
  <option value="1">-- 1</option>
  <option value="[{&quot;key&quot;:&quot;price&quot;}]">-- 2</option>
</select>
```